# How to center contents of ListFragment

Tags: android

I have a simple layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <fragment class="my.test.package.CitiesFragment"
      android:id="@+id/cities" android:layout_weight="4" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
      />
  //....
   </LinearLayout>
```

to the left you can see i have a listfragment that i populate it with cities.
Listfragment consists of simple custom adapter:

```
setListAdapter(new CitiesArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.city_list_item, citiesArrayList));
```

and the city_list_item.xml is:

```
<my.test.package.VerticalTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/verticalTextStyle"
        android:id="@+id/VerticalTextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"          
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
```

VerticalTextView class was taken from this website. the code is here:
[VerticalTextView class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435170/android-vertical-textview-with-image-next-to-it/11493549#1149354)

This is what i have so far:
[image]

As you can see from pic the cities are left aligned. How can I center those cities ??? this is driving me nuts!

***** FOUND THE PROBLEM: its in the verticaltextview class:
    canvas.translate( getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop() );**

getCompoundPaddingLeft right top bottom always return 30 , and the layout gets messed up.
Anybody knows why?????????? or how to fix??

Comment: are you try `android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" ` of your `VerticalTextView` ?

Comment: upon more investigation the above seems to report incorrect width. as a result the text gets offset to the far right.